# How to tag a #log in 1.18?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm working on a treeAxe using commands in 1.18, but I can't figure out how to tag items that are logs and wood.
Here is what have so far:

```
tag @e[type=item,nbt={item:{id:"minecraft:acacia_log"}}] add log
```

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to do with this? My Hope is you are not trying to Target the blocks but the dropped items instead, because if I am right then we can try to figure out what's going wrong, but if I am wrong then what you are trying to do isn't currently possible without mods 

Answer (score 1):

This is the command:

```
execute as @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:oak_log"}}] unless entity @s[tag=log] run tag @s add log
```

This command will detect any item that is of type `oak_log`, so you would need to repeat this one for every log type.

The `unless` part makes the command block only add the tag to logs that aren't tagged already, reducing lag.